# Get-CimInstance CIM_Processor returns multiple "names"

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm trying to get the cpu name for all of the machines on my domain. I'm running the following

```
Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $i.DNSHostName -Class CIM_Processor | Select-Object "PSComputerName", "Name", "NumberOfCores"
```

I'm taking the results of this to build a custom object

```
 $workstationWithIp = [PSCustomObject]@{
            ComputerName = $i.DNSHostName
            CPU = $workstationObj.Name
            Cores = $workstationObj.NumberOfCores
            IP = $ip
            Memory = $memory
            Uptime = $uptimeHours
            OS = $os.Caption + " " + $os.Version
        }
```

My issue is that some of the machines have more than one processor so the "Name" will return multiple results. All of these servers have multiple of the same model so how can I get the result knocked down so I can put it into my custom object as a string? I'm using those custom objects to make a CSV and some will have the cpu name and the core fine but the ones with multiple cpus will give me System.Object[] for the name and core count in the csv

[image]

Comment: Please define "knocked down" - do you just want to grab the first value from both Name and NumberOfCores? Or do you want to combine the information into a new string? Or split the information across multiple object (so you get 1 row per CPU per machine)? In other words: what should the end result look like?

Comment: I'd be happy with just the first value as these servers are all dual CPU with two of the same model and I just want the model, don't care about the cpu count

Comment: Then simply do `$workstationObj.Name |Select-Object -First 1` (same for the NumberOfCores value)

Comment: Well that was super simple. Thanks Mathis. You want to put it as an answer that i can mark so you get whatever stack overflow points or whatever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, a safe way to pick at most 1 item from a potential array/collection of values is by piping to `Select-Object -First 1`:

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
    ComputerName = $i.DNSHostName
    CPU = $workstationObj.Name |Select-Object -First 1
    Cores = $workstationObj.NumberOfCores |Select-Object -First 1
    IP = $ip
    Memory = $memory
    Uptime = $uptimeHours
    OS = $os.Caption + " " + $os.Version
}
```